# Hover to change background image instead of background color

Tags: jquery, css

could someone please guide me with this piece of codes.  Currently when i mouseover a link, it change the background color on another div.  Instead of changing the background color, I'd like to change to another background image.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sample</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <style>
        body { 
            background: #ccc;
            transition:0.5s;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#div-1").hover(
                  function () {
                      $('#top_section').css("background", "#ff9900");
                  }, 
                  function () {
                      $('#top_section').css("background", "#ccc");
                  }
                );

                $("#div-2").hover(
                  function () {
                      $('#top_section').css("background", "red");
                  }, 
                  function () {
                      $('#top_section').css("background", "#ccc");
                  }
                );

                $("#div-3").hover(
                  function () {
                      $('#top_section').css("background", "yellow");
                  }, 
                  function () {
                      $('#top_section').css("background", "#ccc");
                  }
                );
            });
        </script>
    </head>
<body>

    <a id="div-1" href="#"> Orange</a>
    <a id="div-2" href="#">Red</a>
    <a id="div-3" href="#">Yellow</a>
    <div id="top_section" style="height:100px;width:100px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I was changing the line `$('#top_section').css("background", "#ff9900");` to `$('#top_section').css("background-image", "/images/image1.jpg");` but nothing happen when i mouse over the link.
thank you very much,

Comment: You have to correct: `.css("background-image", "/images/image1.jpg");` to `.css("background-image", "url('/images/image1.jpg')");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to surround your image url with `url('...')`.

Try changing `$('#top_section').css("background-image", "/images/image1.jpg");` to `$('#top_section').css("background-image", "url('/images/image1.jpg')");`

Or see http://codepen.io/ckuijjer/pen/giABb for an example

Comment: thank you.  it works. Is it possible to add a little fadein/out to it while the backgroundimage change?

Comment: I think you can't fade in/out an image that's set using the `background-image` css property. If you use a regular `<img />` you can, either by animating the `opacity` css property or using jQuery's `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`. As loading an image might take some time, which might visually interfere with fading, you might want to preload them.

Comment: thanks for the info., also i may not want that effect on the type of the images i'm using...in the background of the images, they're (the graphic designers) using a gradient background, so when it fade - it pixelate and it looks so bad...thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Since /images/image1.jpg is an URL you should do teh following:

```
$('#top_section').css("background-image", "url(/images/image1.jpg)")
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the path is not correct. You can try this code:

```
$('#top_section').css("background-image", "url(../images/image1.jpg)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Or get rid of that mess and use CSS's general sibling selector...

```
#div-1:hover ~ #top_section {
    background-image: url(/images/image1.jpg);
}

#div-2:hover ~ #top_section {
    background-image: url(/images/image2.jpg);
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even shorten you code with one another way, using `data-` attribute

```
<a id="div-1" href="#" data-image="/images/image1.jpg"> Orange</a>
<a id="div-2" href="#" data-image="/images/image2.jpg">Red</a>
<a id="div-3" href="#" data-image="/images/image3.jpg">Yellow</a>
<div id="top_section" style="height:100px;width:100px;"></div>

 $(document).ready(function () {
      $("div").hover( function () {
            var img = $(this).attr('data-image'); // take the attribute value.
            $('#top_section').css("background", "url(img)");
      }, 
      function () {
            $('#top_section').css("background", "#ccc");
      }
 )}
```